# How to delete a channel with a var name with discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am creating a discord bot and I want to create a command to delete channels by their name (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...).
The channels that I want to delete will have as name a single number, so i used the for loop. This is my code; i dont know why this doesn't work, thank you in advance.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
module.exports = {
 name: 'delchannels',
 execute(message) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   let fetchedChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(i);
   fetchedChannel.delete();
  }
 },
};
```

Oh, and yes, I have this error :

```js
    TypeError: fn is not a function
        at Map.find (C:\Users\BillyLeBossWoula\Documents\GitHub\MrSmith\node_modules\@discordjs\collection\dist\index.js:161:17)
        at Object.execute (C:\Users\BillyLeBossWoula\Documents\GitHub\MrSmith\commandes\delchannels.js:7:63)
        at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\BillyLeBossWoula\Documents\GitHub\MrSmith\index.js:26:38)
        at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)
        at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\BillyLeBossWoula\Documents\GitHub\MrSmith\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
        at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\BillyLeBossWoula\Documents\GitHub\MrSmith\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
        at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\BillyLeBossWoula\Documents\GitHub\MrSmith\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
        at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\BillyLeBossWoula\Documents\GitHub\MrSmith\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
        at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\BillyLeBossWoula\Documents\GitHub\MrSmith\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
        at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\BillyLeBossWoula\Documents\GitHub\MrSmith\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Collection.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) requires a function parameter. It will run the given function on every element of the array, and return the first element that satisfies that function. Also, `i` is a number, so you'll have to convert the channel name to a number too.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 let fetchedChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(
  (channel) => +channel.name === i
 );
 fetchedChannel.delete();
}
```

```js
const channels = [
 {
  name: '0',
  id: 123,
 },
 {
  name: '1',
  id: 234,
 },
 {
  name: '2',
  id: 345,
 },
 {
  name: '3',
  id: 456,
 },
];
for (var i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) {
 console.log(channels.find((channel) => +channel.name === i).id);
}
```

---

Just as a tip, I believe you can shorten your function like this:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 let fetchedChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find((c) => +c.name === i);
 fetchedChannel.delete();
}

// change to:
message.guild.channels.cache
 .filter((c) => /^[0-9]$/.test(c.name))
 .forEach((c) => c.delete());
```

Comment: Thank you, I just missed that part ! and I've put this in a try catch block so even if a channel doesn't exist it skips to the next one :D